# Can Google Tag Manager containers fire to two different Google Analytics properties?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-tag-manager

I have two websites, a.com and b.com.

a.com has a GTM container that fires to gaProperty-a.

b.com has a GTM container that fires to gaProperty-a and gaProperty-b.

But in gaProperty-a, I cannot see the b.com numbers entering. The preview mode says it fires alright. But they don't show up. I did it just right now. Do I need to be patient and wait 24hrs? Or isn't this set-up possible at all? Any ideas?

Comment: You can check GA real time numbers - you should definitely see your session there strieght away.

Comment: Check the filters in your view. Maybe you are filtering all hosts except a.com